# cleartool describe -ahlink -all filename

Tags: unix, clearcase

I am doing a describe on a file:

```
ct desc -ahlink -all 5.txt
 5.txt@@/main/52
 Hyperlinks:

 Merge <- /vobs/TESTVOB/5.txt@@/main/test_branch/1
 Merge <- /vobs/TESTVOB/5.txt@@/main/test_branch/2
```

Is there a way in clearcase using -fmt something to get the last hyperlink from the describe command without using unix commands to achieve it?

If not can someone suggest me the appropriate unix command to get the desired output?

I tried this command:

```
  ct desc -ahlink -all 5.txt | grep Merge | cut -d "-" -f2

and this gives me: 
   /vobs/TESTVOB/5.txt@@/main/test_branch/1
   /vobs/TESTVOB/5.txt@@/main/test_branch/2

 I only want:
   /vobs/TESTVOB/5.txt@@/main/test_branch/2
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a native way to get that last hyperlink.

So using a unix command like [`tail`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) should be enough:

```
ct desc -ahlink -all 5.txt | grep Merge | tail -1 | cut -d "-" -f2
```

Comment: Thanks VonC. Accepting your answer. The only change in the above command would be : tail -1 instead of tail -n 1 which I am sure is what you intended.